# Android 13 FileProvider: Unable to access file descriptor from URI despite granting temporary permissions

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-securityexception, android-13

For some time we have been using the `FileProvider` APIs to reading/writing a file in App A's internal data directory (/data/data/app.a.package/files/someFile) from App B using a `BroadcastReceiver`.  Here is a flow of the communication between the apps:

```
App B -- broadcast intent requesting someFile --> App A
App A -> use FileProvider API to get URI for someFile 
App A -- broadcast intent with someFile URI --> App B
App B -> open file descriptor of URI and write contents
```

Here is a snippet of what has worked and continues to work on devices with Android 12 and lower (targetSdk bumped up to latest 33 on both App A and App B) but fails to work on Android 13 devices:

```kotlin
val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "app.a.package.fileprovider", someFile)
if (fileUri != null) {
    resultIntent.putExtra(FILE_URI_EXTRA, fileUri)

   // We need to explicitly grant permissions to the package that will request the URI from this FileProvider
   context.grantUriPermission(
      "app.b.package", fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    )

    // Also tried adding these for good measure, not needed on Android 12 devices or lower, doesn't help on Android 13
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

    context.sendBroadcast(resultIntent)
}
```

On the `BroadcastReceiver` side, here is a minimal snippet that generates a `SecurityException` only on Android 13 devices:

```java
                Uri fileUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(FILE_URI_EXTRA);
                if (fileUri == null)
                    return; // failed to get data
                try {
                    /*
                     * Get the content resolver instance for this context, and use it
                     * to get a ParcelFileDescriptor for the file.
                     */
                    ParcelFileDescriptor inputPFD = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(fileUri, "rw");
                    if (inputPFD == null)
                        return;
                    FileDescriptor licenseFileFD = inputPFD.getFileDescriptor();
```

On Android 13, attempting to access the file descriptor is resulting in `androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{37fcd9d 7629:app.b.package/u0a245} (pid=7629, uid=10245) that is not exported from UID 10244`

I've been combing through Google's behavior change documentation but can't seem to pinpoint what would cause this breaking change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the issue, it is related to the package visibility behavior changes.  I needed to make sure that both App A and  App B had the following package visibilities.

App A:

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="app.b.package" />
</queries>
```

App B:

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="app.a.package" />
</queries>
```

The following logcat log brought me to this conclusion:
`AppsFilter: interaction: PackageSetting{3ff3d93 com.tha.main/10244} -> PackageSetting{bc58197 com.tha.activator/10245} BLOCKED`